# Why does my loop run multiple times continuously without prompting me for input?

Tags: c++

```
       while (inputstr != "The End") {
            // Read in a String from the user
            std::cout << "Please enter a string:\n";
            std::cin >> inputstr;


       }
```

This is the code I have written, in C++. For some reason, whenever I enter a string, if the string has multiple words to it, like "hello hello", then "Please enter a string:" gets printed 2 times consecutively, instead of only once. If I enter a one word string, it only prints once. If I enter a 3 word string, it prints that line 3 times, and so on.

Comment: `std::cin >> inputstr` promises to read one whitespace-delimited sequence of characters.  It will never extract `"The End"`, as a single word.  Are you trying to read a full line of characters?  Are you trying to read multiple lines?  Think about what would signify that `std::cin` is "done" reading characters.

Comment: Yes. That's how `std::cin` works together with `std::string`. If you want to read a whole line, use `std::getline`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code , `std::cin >> inputstr;`cin will read only one word (means a string before space). After space cin will consider the input as next string.

Solution for this is to use `getline()` function at the place of `cin` like :

```
while (inputstr != "The End") {
  // Read in a String from the user
  std::cout << "Please enter a string:\n";
  // std::cin >> inputstr;
  getline (cin , inputstr);
}
```